# Onload events seq

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experimenting with write method & onload event. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.write('body loaded!')">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <img onload="document.write('img loadeld!')" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" />
    </body>
</html>
```

What would be be the sequence of events in this case? Would the browser first create body element & call "body loaded" or the img element would be created first?

Comment: What happens when you run the code in your browser?

Comment: You want to know when the IMG is *created* or *loaded*? Two very different things.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Maybe use a debugger like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/). Your question does not indicate that you ran into any problems. I think you will learn a lot more if you step through the code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a `div` than use `innerHTML` property to write something in to it. A sample code would be:

```
<img src = "hi.jpg" onLoad = "function1()"/>
<div id = "xyz"></div>
```

Javascript part:

```
<script>
function function1(){
document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = "Imageloaded!!";
}
</script>
```